# How to read a table from a Box shared link (url) in R?

Tags: r, box, rcurl, read.table

I need to read in a text file shared via Box.com - I'll use `mtcars.txt` as an example.

```
 WES.ped.exp <-
 read.table("https://ucsf.box.com/s/tht30egddqjqlq3koucqy7rhtzkh3ydi")
```

Problem is the shared link takes me to a viewer interface, from where one is supposed to click `Download`, and not *directly* to the plain `.txt` file.

When reading the table, it just reads HTML lines, like so:

[image]

I've tried `curl`, `scan` and just `read.table` , any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an example of a Box url handy, but I know Dropbox appends `?dl=0` (i.e. download = false) to the end of urls to take you to the viewer. For Dropbox urls, changing to `?dl=1` (i.e. download = true) to get the raw file.

Comment: The Box URL doesn't have a `?dl=` section :(

Comment: Can you post either the url you're working with, or another example of one? Or if you're stuck working with an HTML file, you can probably scrape data out of the table with `rvest`

Comment: Just added an example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the share setting of the file in question. Click on "Share", go to the settings, and make sure the file's shared link is set to "Anyone with the link can view and download this file", in order to generate a direct link.

Go to the little settings icon, copy the "Direct Link", and paste it into the following:

```
read.table("https://ucsf.box.com/shared/static/whateverthelinksays.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not seeing a direct link option because I had not set the sharing mode to "anyone with the link", but instead it was at the default "anyone in this file", which does not generate a direct link.